# Imprimir JSON.Parse

Tags: javascript, json, parse, localstorage

Bom dia,

Tenho uma variável que armazena dados vindos de um `localStorage`, que por sua vez contem os dados abaixo:

```
Array[3]
0:"{"Token":-6742.075757575755,"Solicitacao":"3359659","Justificativa":"jjjj"}"
1:"{"Token":-57645.84848484848,"Solicitacao":"10","Justificativa":""}"
2:"{"Token":-57645.84848484848,"Solicitacao":"10","Justificativa":"asdasd"}"
length:3
```

**Código**:

```
    var tbHistoricos = window.localStorage.getItem("tbHistoricos");
    tbHistoricos = JSON.parse(tbHistoricos);
```

O que quero é imprimir o conteudo de cada linha por tag. Para cada linha eu imprimo com:

```
tbHistoricos[numero_que_eu_quero]
```

Mas não quero a linha toda, quero cada `tag` individual, mas da maneira abaixo não funciona:

```
tbHistoricos[numero_que_eu_quero].Token
```

Como posso fazer?

Comment: O que te dá estes logs: `console.log(typeof window.localStorage.getItem("tbHistoricos"), window.localStorage.getItem("tbHistoricos"));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é porque o conteúdo de cada posição é uma string e não um objeto, por isso você não conseguiu acessar com .Token.

```
$ node
> var arr = [{"Token":-6742.075757575755,"Solicitacao":"3359659","Justificativa":"jjjj"},
{"Token":-57645.84848484848,"Solicitacao":"10","Justificativa":""},
{"Token":-57645.84848484848,"Solicitacao":"10","Justificativa":"asdasd"}]

> arr[0].Token
-6742.075757575755
```

Ai nesse caso você precisa fazer o parse de cada posição

```
var arr = window.localStorage.getItem("tbHistoricos");
arr = JSON.parse(arr);
arr = arr.map(i => JSON.parse(i));
console.log(arr[0].Token);
```

ai sim vai funcionar corretamente.